# Creating new variable by using a previous one

Tags: r, count, sum, dplyr

Hi I am learning how to use the R language. I have a data set (df), which has 3 categorical variables (Session, ID, Assessed). I am trying to create a new variable (Total Assessed) that consists of the sum/count of the nº of "Y" in the Assessed column, per Session. I tried to use the commands count, sum, filter, mutate, to try to add the new variable "Total Assessed" to my data frame, but I haven't achieved the result I wanted. This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3arNN.png) shows the result I would like to have.(And it is also how it looks like, but it hasn't the last variable). Can you please help me?
Below are the commands I tried to use, but for this or other reason didn't work... I feel like I am close to the answer, but using the commands in the wrong order or missing a step.

```
> df %>% group_by(Session) %>% filter(Assessed == "Y") # it didn't gave me the count of "Y"
> df <- df %>% group_by(Session, Assessed) %>% filter(Assessed == "Y") # it didn't gave me the count of "Y"

> df <- df %>% group_by(Session, Assessed) %>% filter(Assessed == "Y") %>% tally() # This was close, beacuse it counted the "Y" per session. However, it completly ignored sessions that only had "N". I need this sessions to appear has "0" in "Total Assessed".
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please add a sample of your code even if it's not working so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: You are right, sorry I forgot to mention I was working with R. I didn't include the commands, because I tried so different combinations that I thought it might be more confusing. I included now the ones I think that are close to the right answer (or one of the answers). Do you think it is good like this? Thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

The trick is to temporarly transform the Assessed variable into a nmeric one. And then use group_by, mutate and the sum comands (I am not sure, but I think the first two belong to the dplyr package). Then I can return the Assessed to character again.

```
> df$Assessed <- as.numeric(df$Assessed)
> df %>% df <- group_by (Session) %>% mutate (Total Assessed = sum(Assessed))
> df$Assessed <- as.character(df$Assessed)
```